# ECONNRESET when attempting rabbitmq node.js tutorial/example on Centos 6.4

Tags: rabbitmq

I am getting the Error: read ECONNRESET] when  I try the example in https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/send.js. 
I have tried both node v0.9.10 and v0.10.25. Is anybody having a similar issue? Both the sender and receiver are on the same machine, a Centos 6.4 based VM. 
I am launching them as 'node send.js' and 'node receiver.js'

Tks in advance.
-bn

Answer (score 0):

According to this GitHub comment https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues/300#issuecomment-33929955, this happens because RabbitMQ is responding to the conn.disconnnect() FIN with a RST which is causing the ECONNRESET.

Until RabbitMQ will fix this, your best solution is to filter it in the client code.

Comment: "best solution is to filter it in the client code" -- can you elaborate? maybe with a code sample?